# im trying to insert placeholders into a form but they disappear as soon as the page loads! Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, html

The Website in question is "http://test.vesperdesign.com/index-6.html" in case anyone wants to see the form, i've tried many tricks and not working in any browser, it disappears as soon as the page loads, .

Comment: im assuming it has something to do with your TMForm.js

Comment: u need to provide some code here, how ,when and where are you inserting the placeholder?

Comment: Maybe from somewhere along lines 151 of TMForm.js and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove line 188 from TMForm.js problem will be solved. I don't really know  how that would affect all the other code from that js, but if you know the code and see that line isn't necessary at all remove it. That may stop those placeholders disappear.